# Python - Opening a Text File and Appending Lines via raw_input

Tags: python, append, raw-input

I'm trying to add on to this code so where I can append lines to a text file via user input. This is what I have so far:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

print "Let's read and write to a file now!"

raw_input ("Press enter when ready to proceed...")

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Let's copy one file and put it into another file!"
print "I'm going to copy from %s to %s!" % (from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file you picked is %d bytes long, cool huh?" % len(indata)
print "Does the output file you are trying to make exist? %r" % exists(to_file)

print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C or Command+C to abort."
raw_input("Press enter when ready to proceed...")
print "Are you SURE that you want to continue?... This could blow the world up. CTRL-C or Command+C to abort."
raw_input("Press enter when ready to proceed...")
print "Last chance... Do you really want to risk doing off with the human race?... CTRL-C or Command+C to abort."
raw_input("Press enter when ready to proceed...")

print "Alright! I'm doing it!"

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Oh... We are still alive. Well, have fun with your new file!"


out_file.close()
in_file.close()

print "Let's try and append a line to the new copied file!"
raw_input("Press enter when ready to proceed...")

print "Type in the file path for the file you want to edit!: "
filename = raw_input(">")

with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(raw_input())
```

When it asked me for the file path, I type this (on a mac):

```
/Users/Ross/Desktop/School/Intro\ To\ Python/lab5/readcopy.txt
```

It returns me with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ross/Desktop/School/Intro To Python/lab5/readcopy.py", line 43, in <module>
    with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Ross/Desktop/School/Intro\\ To\\     Python/lab5/readcopy.txt '
```

Any input as to how I can do this? Also, is the code correct in wanting to add new lines with the user input?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you assigning the result of `raw_input()` anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I'm still learning all of this.

Comment: @o11c Because it prompts the user to press enter to continue on with the next section of code if that is what you are wondering.

Comment: You can't use the result of `raw_input()` unless you assign it to a variable ... wait. you're only using that as a "press enter"? My bad.

Comment: When using `raw_input()` you need to store that value in a variable . Then use that variable to write into a file or do any work you want to. Without storing it in a variable you'll just lose it

Comment: So now what I don't get is: when is it prompting you for a filename?

Comment: okay, I'm stupid, I didn't even notice the code scrolled.

Comment: The IOError indicates the it is not able to find the path to the file. When asked for file path use /Users/Ross/Desktop/School/Intro To Python/lab5/readcopy.txt without any escaping for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes are not part of the filename. Rather, they exist solely to escape characters that are otherwise meaningful, in this case to the shell. `raw_input` does not need any escaping.

Just enter `/Users/Ross/Desktop/School/Intro To Python/lab5/readcopy.txt`, or better use a relative path.